# jQuery.Callbacks vs jQuery.on/off/trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

What's the major difference between the two and in which cases should I use callbacks instead of off/on/trigger and vice versa?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing.  Those are 2 completely different concepts, used for solving completely different problems.

Comment: Ahh ok. The only reason I asked was because over here: https://gist.github.com/1321768 it had multiple ways to fixing the problem, and callbacks and on/off/triger were two of them

Comment: Looking at the link, I'd argue that the use of `on` and `off` there is a bit of a hack.  I personally would use callbacks compared to binding fake "events" in order to call methods.